# Phantom <li> within carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having more trouble with this infographic. There seems to be a phantom `<li>` appearing at the end of the carousel. Does anyone know how this has appeared?

http://weaver-wp.weavertest.com/radiation-infographic/

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: I'm not seeing it when using chrome.

Comment: @Kyle Rogers If you scroll to the last proper slide, there is an empty slide to the right of that, and not sure how it's appeared

Comment: You've got unclosed `<p class="description">`'s after your second `<li>`. Fix these and see if it sorts out the problem (search and replace `<p></div>` with `</p></div>` -- there are at least 3).

Comment: @stealthyninja Thanks for noticing that :) Unfortunately it hasn't solved the issue. I'm not sure if elements are appearing off the side of the final `<li>` to force another slide to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dalogi: Still can't find the issue, so this will have to be the band-aid for now --

```
$('#radiation-infographic').tinycarousel({ 
    pager: true, 
    interval: false, 
    callback: function(element, index) {
        // hide 'next' button when on last slide; unhide when not
        index == 30 ? $('a.next').hide() : $('a.next').show();

        console.log(element, index);
    }
});
```

I'll update my answer if I have a break-through with a better solution.

Comment: Cheers stealthyninja. Used a similar snippet of code to the one you supplied, but problem resolved: callback: function (element, index) {
                  if (index === 30) {
                      $('.next').hide();
                  }
                  else {
                      $('.next').show();
                  }
                  console.log(element, index);
              }

Answer (score 1):

Might this be the cause?

```
<div id="carousel"> 
<ul>    
    <li></li>       
</ul>
```

Validator also says there is an unclose div ( wrapper div ) Doubt thats the issue though

Comment: Just removed that and it is still playing up :(

Comment: try this out `for (var i=1; i <= 31; i++) {`
try to use `for (var i=0; i <= 30; i++) {` or `for (var i=1; i <= 30; i++) {`

Comment: Unfortunately not. The canvas elements are all being called correctly, so this doesn't affect the final slide

Comment: Ok next try :p `if ($("#myCanvas_31")) {
       $(a.next).append("class=\"disable\"");
        }` ....Maybe `$(a.next).addClass("disable");` do the trick, or `$(a.next).hide();` ....`$(a.buttons next).hide();`

Comment: @Basti Tried all of these before posting and to no avail. Thanks though :)

Comment: Whoa what a tricky one :( Sorry that were all of my ideas for now. But try playing with the hide function function a little more. Pretty sure it can be solved with it

Comment: Say, what happen if you use the :last selector? `$(".overview:last").hide();`... Does it actually hide your real last li?

Comment: @Basti: +1 for contributing and getting involved on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last `<li>` contains the last 'slide' of your content. Is the 'navigating past the last slide' the behavior you're trying to suppress? If so, hide the 'right' navigation button when you're viewing the last slide and the 'left' navigation button when you're viewing the first slide, preventing the user from scrolling past the beginning or end of the carousel.

Comment: That could work only the solution is quite dirty. The slider is not working correctly because he forgot to put a classname on the div that is acting like the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, you have to set a class 'viewport' on the object div.radiationViewport. The reason that could be the problem is because the script does calculations using the metrics of that object. Like calculating the 'leftover space'.